# Batch file closing immediately once launched

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch script that is supposed to be the menu of a game. I haven't finished it yet but I figured out that when i run it it immediately closes. If anyone could please help me figure out the issue I would greatly appreciate it, thank you. Here is the code:

``````
@echo off
set save_file_path=C:\Users\maxqs\Desktop\Coding Projects\Personal Project\PathRPG\save_file.txt
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo                                :oooo+/`                -:      dy          :ooooo/.     `ooooo/-       -+syys+-                                      
echo                                oMo::/yMy               dM      Nm          sMo::/yMy    `Md::/oNm.   :mm+-.-:od+                                     
echo                                oM/    hM-  :dddddy-   hNMhhh.  Nmohdmd/    sM:    mM`   `Mh    /My  :Mh                                              
echo                                oM/  `/Nd   ``   `dN    dM      NN:   hM.   sM/..-sMo    `Mh   -dN:  hM-   `````                                      
echo                                oMmddhs/    -sdhhhNM`   dM      Nm    oM:   sMdydMd`     `MNdddy+`   yM:   +hhmMo                                     
echo                                oM/        .Md`   yM`   dM      Nm    oM:   sM:  /Nm:    `Mh         :Md`     /Mo                                     
echo                                oM/        `mm/:/sNM`   sMo:/`  Nm    oM:   sM:   `sMy`  `Mh          :dNs/::/yM+                                     
echo                                -/.         `/oo+.:/     :+o+`  //    -/`   -/.     -//  `/:            ./ooo+:.                                      
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
echo.
echo            [1] Start game
echo            [2] End game                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
set /p input= >
if %input%== 1 goto end_menu
if %input%== 2 goto start_game

:start_game

echo            [1] New game
echo            [2] Continue
echo            [3] Options
set /p input= >
if %input%== 1 goto new_game
if %input%== 2 goto continue_game
if %input%== 3 goto options

:new_game

echo 000#>%save_file_path%
CALL game.bat
goto end_menu

:end_menu
``````

Comment: `>` is a special character in command processing (in fact, you use it for redirection farther down in the code). You have to escape it for the prompt, like `set /p input= ^>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you code should look like, it uses doublequotes, and parentheses to protect intended strings, and choice.exe as the correct and appropriate command to use for requesting use input.

``````
@echo off
set "save_file_path=C:\Users\maxqs\Desktop\Coding Projects\Personal Project\PathRPG\save_file.txt"
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                :oooo+/`                -:      dy          :ooooo/.     `ooooo/-       -+syys+-
echo                                oMo::/yMy               dM      Nm          sMo::/yMy    `Md::/oNm.   :mm+-.-:od+
echo                                oM/    hM-  :dddddy-   hNMhhh.  Nmohdmd/    sM:    mM`   `Mh    /My  :Mh
echo                                oM/  `/Nd   ``   `dN    dM      NN:   hM.   sM/..-sMo    `Mh   -dN:  hM-   `````
echo                                oMmddhs/    -sdhhhNM`   dM      Nm    oM:   sMdydMd`     `MNdddy+`   yM:   +hhmMo
echo                                oM/        .Md`   yM`   dM      Nm    oM:   sM:  /Nm:    `Mh         :Md`     /Mo
echo                                oM/        `mm/:/sNM`   sMo:/`  Nm    oM:   sM:   `sMy`  `Mh          :dNs/::/yM+
echo                                -/.         `/oo+.:/     :+o+`  //    -/`   -/.     -//  `/:            ./ooo+:.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            [1] Start game
echo            [2] End game
choice /c 12 /n /m ">"
if errorlevel 2 goto end_menu

:start_game

echo            [1] New game
echo            [2] Continue
echo            [3] Options
choice /c 123 /n /m ">"
if errorlevel 3 goto options
if errorlevel 2 goto continue_game

:new_game

(echo 000#) > "%save_file_path%"
CALL "game.bat"
pause
goto end_menu

:end_menu
``````

BTW, I removed the unnecessarily pointless and wasteful trailing space characters from your code, all 5376 of them obviously increased your script size by 5Kb too.